# Updating in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, 15.04

I'm a new Ubuntu user so I installed it using `virtualbox` and it says that I have a lot of obsolete packages. How do I update the packages? I tried doing `sudo apt-get update` and it updates but on next boot same thing happens.

Answer (score 0):

You can update packages with `Software Updater`:

- Click the Unity icon in the Unity Dash (usually the first icon in the left bar)
- Type "Software Updater" and click on the first result
- Choose the packages to update
- Click "Install now"

Answer (score 0):

`update` is only part of the task. That command updates the list of package information, but doesn't actually change your installation.

After updating the packages, *upgrade* the packages

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```